# Sending automatic e- mail on GOOGLE Spreadsheets

Tags: email, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Good Morning,

I am developing a lending spreadsheet books ...

Like it when a column was written " LATE " ( let's assume it is cell D2 ) , an email was sent ( we assume that the registered e- mail was in cell G2 ) automatic for the user who took the borrowed book, saying that the delivery date has passed.

It is possible? Although not natively ...

If possible with the code

Grateful.

Comment: Please review the following overflow item:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552610/write-a-google-apps-script-to-send-e-mails-to-users-who-submitted-a-form-10-days

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link and you can create otherwise if you want i can do for u but you have to pay :p
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/add-reminders-to-spreadsheet